# Why do I need the WAKE_LOCK and SET_ALARM permissions?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-permissions, android-wake-lock

I am developing an android app and testing it on my Moto G X1032. I had alarms and notifications working fine when it was running 5.1 GPE without any special permissions.

The application uses the AlarmManager, which sets an alarm in the future like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, reminder.Due.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Then in the receiver, it launches a notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
builder.setContentTitle("My App")
        .setContentText(reminder.Due.toString())
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_revise)
        .setLights(Color.GREEN, 750, 1400)
        .setAutoCancel(true);

Notification notification = builder.build();
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationMgr.notify(0, notification);
```

It was working fine, waking the phone up (just CPU not screen) and making the usual sound, vibrating and blinking the light, then I changed a custom rom (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2780873) and that all stopped working, instead it now made the sound when I manually awoke the device.

So, after reading, I put in permissions for a wake lock and surrounded my code like so:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "myapp");
wakeLock.acquire();

NotificationManager notificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationMgr.notify(0, notification);

wakeLock.release();
```

So now it makes the sound without a manual wake, but the light does not blink but instead is permenantly on until the notification is seen.

Also I would like to know what is the purpose of the SET_ALARM permission when I could set an alarm without it? And why is it now not working without the wake lock code and permission, and why the light stays on instead of blinking? Has the rom modified something or is it not a standard in the first place.

Comment: "then I changed a custom rom... and that all stopped working" -- ask the developers of that custom ROM. "Also I would like to know what is the purpose of the SET_ALARM permission when I could set an alarm without it?" -- `SET_ALARM` isn't used for `AlarmManager`. AFAIK, it is only used for alarm clock apps. It is not especially well-documented...

Comment: @CommonsWare Many thanks for your reply, I have already asked on XDA but I think the rom is abandoned.